# can you create java file from the class file? Decompile

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I recently created a project in Netbeans using VirtualBox on which i installed windows XP (Not activiated)
My Windows required me to activate and would not allow me access to my files on the computer before i activate it, i stupidly went and uninstalled XP and reinstalled it, thinking i'll have access to all the files from the JAR file i created

I want to know if theres any way i can use the class files of the project i created, to create new java files so that i can edit the code in netbeans ??

Please if anyone can shed some light on this topic, if its at all posible to gain access to the forms java content i created. Im new to programming and this is something above my knowledge (i hope this makes sense)

If not possible please let me know what an absolute idiot i am, so that i can start re creating the project from scratch ... Sigh, and thank you

Comment: i think title is wrong..You want class files from jar again ?

Comment: @ Sercan Ozdemir, it is wrong, thank you, i'll try and fix now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jar/class file is compiled bytecode that is not human-readable... *but* with Java it is easily converted back. Look into a program like [JavaDecompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/).<sup>1</sup> This is not my program but I use it and I find it workable for my needs.

<sup>1</sup> If this is considered spam I'll gladly invalidate the link.

Comment: @KarolS Thanks. I just realize that to fix it.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, you just made the worst day soo much better !! I have all my java files that I need now, the imports and layout changed but i can go change and work with it atleast

Comment: @ArmandtBurger Yeah, it's known to change a bit but at least the gist of the files is saved.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote: You are lucky that its Java. In many other languages like C++ that would hardly be possible. The difference is that Java does not compile the source code to *machine code*. That step is hardly reversible since for example all variable names are lost. Try to understand a non-trivial piece of code without helpful variable names...

Java instead compiles the source code to **byte code** which then is interpreted by Java on runtime. That byte cold holds way more information about the original source code than machine code.